# convergence in measure of min $(f_n,g)$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I was reading a proof of a convergence in measure variant of fatou's lemma earlier and there was a seemingly easy part of it I just could not verify.

Assume $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of unsigned functions on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,  \mu)$ converging in measure to some function $f$. Let $g \leq f$ be bounded. Then $\min(f_n,g) \to \min(f,g)$ in measure.

It sounds very obvious, but somehow I couldn't prove it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Would you clarify "unsigned"?

Comment: $f_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f_n \xrightarrow{P} f$ iff for every subsequence $f_{n_k}$ there is a further subsequence $f_{n_{k_l}}$ that converges to $f$ almost surely. This should imply your claim.